# Installing Sensenet on Local Host

Tags: sensenet

I had installed sensenet using nuget package manager and visual studio and able to run sensenet using visual studio. But when i tried using IIS and same packages,  error is coming. i didnt find any installation guide to run on IIS local host.

I had installed all the modules (Web pages, Work space using visual studio)

[Error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5USGf.png)

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying this just today and faced exactly this issue.

It seems you have installed Sensenet.Services DB with integrated authentication. In that case when you host the Site on IIS, it does not have access to logged in user. It works under AppPool identity user context.

As I see you have 2 quick options.

Configure the AppPool to run under a windows account which has access to DB or
Make necessary changes to connectionstrings to access db with DB account (Username/Password instead of integrated security)

I hope someone who knows about sensenet more than me can answer if there is a easy way to do that.

I am stuck on the next step. For me, it starts but when browsing to default site, it throws a 404. Whereas, just like you, everything works fine when running using IIS Express in Visual Studio. I really hope someone can guide us through this. Otherwise my next option is to try [LogicalDoc](https://www.logicaldoc.com/download-logicaldoc-community) or [Nuxeo](https://www.nuxeo.com/downloads/) :(.

I really want to give Sensenet a try. It looks very promising.

Comment: I used DB authentication, not windows.  and while installing using command prompt after package download i had given the user name and password of DB server. But iam unable to understand how it works using IIS. I tried modifying the connection string in Web config file but error came. If somebody who knows guides step by step it will be very useful as sensenet seems very robust and powerful platform compared to any other over hyped platforms. i never tried Nuxeo as it is java based. Logical doc is not upto the expectation as iam looking for a Enterprise CMS not a DMS.

Comment: Are you sure all your connection strings target the same db and they contain the same username and password? From the error message this looks like an Entity Framework connection string, maybe there is a section in your web config that is not necessary and try to connect using integrated authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I've usually got this error when I'd forgot to set the pool user. Application pool user must be an owner of the sensenet database. On local environment maybe the quickest way to set the windows user to the pool. It's a good enough way for development purposes.

For multi-user environment consider to create a technical user in windows and set it on both the pool and for the db. For example if "the user" 
IIS: Application Pools / "the pool" / Advanced Settings / Process Model / Identity / set "the user"
Management Studio: DB Server / Security / Logins / "the user" / Properties / User Mapping / "the database" / check db_owner